# Disposing in nested using statement

Tags: c#

Consider this class:

```
class Person : IDisposable
{
    public Person(int age)
    {

    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose");
    }
}
```

and this code:

```
using (Person perosn = new Person(0))
{
   using (Person child = new Person(1))
   {
   }
}
```

When run this code output is two `Dispose` in console.

I change the class:

```
class Person : IDisposable
{
    public Person(int age)
    {
        if (age == 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Person");
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose");
    }
}
```

I get exception and both class does not dispose.

So why when I throw new exception in child's constructor, both classes are not disposed?

Comment: This doesn't worth much upvotes as question is providing wrong information.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. When constructor in inner using throws an exception I still see outer using disposing of class correctly.

Comment: Some useful reading is Eric Lippert's post about the interactions of exceptions and `using` statements [here](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/02/26/resources-vs-exceptions/#.UxQ2bnVdWlg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not seeing the same results:

```
try {
    using (Person perosn = new Person(0))
    {
        using (Person child = new Person(1))
        {
        }
    }
} catch {
    Console.WriteLine("Caught exception");
}
```

Output:

```
Dispose
Caught exception
```

Comment: I think the asker wanted two know why the output `Disposed` is written only once. I don't think your answer touches that?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: The asker said "both class does not dispose", meaning that `Disposed` is not written at all. On the other hand, English is obviously not his first language, so your interpretation *might* be correct as well.

Answer (score 3):

`using` statement for reference types is transformed into

```
{
    ResourceType resource = expression;
    IDisposable d = (IDisposable)resource;
    try {
        statement;
    }
    finally {
        if (d != null) d.Dispose();
    }
}
```

As you see, initialization is performed before `try`, so when constructor throws an exception `Dispose` is not called. That's why you see only one `Disposed` string printed.

Check **8.13 The using statement** in C# specification to see more.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you did *not* add a `catch` statement (as seen in [Blorgbeard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22139640/87698)) but rather just ran your example in Visual Studio?

In that case, [Visual Studio will stop execution at the moment the first exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/164433/87698), so yes, `person` will not be disposed. This, however, is a "feature" of the development environment and won't affect your program after deployment.