# AggregateException during debugging forces restart of ForAll body

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, plinq, aggregateexception

I'm experiencing really strange behavior, which I cannot neither understand nor explain. I was able to create a really simple sample to demonstrate that. That was reproduced on VS.Net 2013 & 2015 on different machines with several target .Net versions.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Sample
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExecuteInParallel(new[]
            {
                new Tuple<string, Action>("Task1", () => { }),
                new Tuple<string, Action>("Task2", () => { throw new Exception("Exception"); })
            });
        }

        private static void ExecuteInParallel(Tuple<string, Action>[] tasks)
        {
            tasks.AsParallel().ForAll(x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting " + x.Item1);
                x.Item2();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When you just run that code without debugging, you receive what expected: two task started, one failed, and AggregateException details in console:

```
Starting Task1
Starting Task2

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Exception
   at Sample.Program.<Main>b__1() in d:\temp\ConsoleApplication40\ConsoleApplication40\Program.cs:line 13
...
```

But when you start the same code with debugging, results are really weird. First, you receive AggregateException:

[image: VS.2013 AggregateException]

But when you click Continue, it just starts both tasks again and again - here is sample output from Console:

```
Starting Task1
Starting Task2
Starting Task1
Starting Task2
Starting Task1
Starting Task2
Starting Task1
Starting Task2
```

I was using two tasks to demonstrate that they are both restarting; you can comment out empty one and receive the same confusing results.

My question here - is this a VS.Net bug, or some feature I don't understand?

Is there a way to debug in a "normal" way here?

Comment: Answer from @JackZhaiMSFT moved me in right direction - looks like that's how **Unwind the callstack on unhandled exceptions** feature works. Here is (not accepted but highly upvoted) answer for similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/23002780/2170171 Voting for duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I can repro this issue in my side, the real issue is that the whole .exe/program was not exited like the messages we often get if a console app was exited:

**The program '[xxx] ConsoleApplication12.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).**

To really reprove it, for example, not really debug your app using the F5, just debug your app using the F11(Step Into)(Debug app one step by one step), you would find that the app couldn't be exited after the second exception showed.

Another way to prove it is that you could add try...catch in following code:

```
          tasks.AsParallel().ForAll(x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting " + x.Item1);
                x.Item2();
            });
```

And then debug your app again, you would find that it would not output the messages again by again and the app was exited even if it still has the first exception
[image]

**Update: I just find that one debug option really impacts the issue.**
If I disable this option, it would not debug the app again by again after I click "Break" or "Continue" in that pop window.

[image]

Comment: While you demonstrated that there's an issue indeed, I don't see how that answers the question. For me "program not exited" is just the result of weird debugger behavior

Comment: Thanks, that answer moved me in a right direction - please see my comment to question above.

Comment: @ Lanorkin, thanks for sharing your useful information here, this issue is similar to that link provided by you, but you don't have to edit this issue as the duplicate since different members asked this issue and it doesn't mark the answer.  if you accept it as the answer, if possible, you could post your comment as the answer here, so it could help other members who meet the same issue. Anyway, have a nice day:)